# modifying postscript file: shifting content and resizing page or crop content

Tags: crop, postscript, convert

I have a program that produces postscript file.  The file has a text block vertically in the middle of an A4 page.

[image: Text block in the middle of A4 page, the original document]

The text block fits A5 size in landscape mode. I would like to convert the ps file from A4 size portrait mode to A5 size landscape mode by shifting and/or rotating the text.

I tried to use pstops tool:

pstops -w14.8cm -h10.5cm 0(0cm,-7.5cm) file0.ps out1.ps

which gives:

[image]

or

pstops -pa5 0L(25.3cm,0cm) file0.ps out2.ps

which gives:

[image]

It seems that pstops crops the original A4 size to A5, and only after cropping it shifts/rotates the page. Therefore the original text block is cut and only part of it goes to the new ps file.

Is there any way I can solve this? Need not to be pstops but have to be done automatically without user intervention in a script. If it takes more steps and/or tools it's OK too.

Comment: This seems more to be a postscript question than a latex related question. Might not be suitable here

Comment: @daleif: Yes, you're right. The reasons I asked this here are 1) pstops / psutils package is part of ctan repository, 2) I couldn't find better (more specific active) forum to ask it. If you have any suggestion where to raise this problem, please post it.

Comment: stackoverflow would be appropriate for this, or unix.sx